# LINQ Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I want to generate expression trees using the API for the following:

```cs
var managers = dataContext.Employees.Where(e => e.Subordinates.Any());
```

Additionally, how do I then generate the expression tree to do this:

```cs
var managedEmployees = managers.ToDictionary(key => key.Manager, value => value.Subordinates.Select(s => s.FullName));
```

I've come up with the following so far for the .Where(), but it errors because it doesn't like the type parameters in `new Type[] { typeof(Func<Employee, IEnumerable<Employee>>) }`.

```cs
ParameterExpression employeesParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");
MemberExpression subordinatesProperty = Expression.Property(employeesParameter, typeof(Employee).GetProperty("Subordinates"));
MethodCallExpression hasSubordinates = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
  "Any",
  new Type[] { typeof(Employee) },
  subordinatesProperty);
LambdaExpression whereLambda = Expression.Lambda(hasSubordinates, employeesParameter);
MethodCallExpression whereExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
  "Where",
  new Type[] { typeof(Func<Employee, IEnumerable<Employee>>) },
  dataContext.Employees.AsQueryable(),
  whereLambda);
```

Comment: for a starter "where" should be called via methodinfo invoke. stuff inside the brackets is expression

Comment: No, this works for me if I remove the Any() out of the Where() and make it something else like say Where(e => e.EmployedDate > '1/1/2013'). I can then change the type from Func<Employee, IEnumerable<Employee>> to Employee and it works as expected. The problem is entirely with that Any() function, and I can't figure out what type to supply.

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once. If you have something to add, edit your original question.

Comment: In fairness, the other question didn't get an answer.

Comment: The other question seemed to completely baffle everyone that looked at it. So I attempted this question using more generic code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got this. The type parameters on `Any` and `Where` need to be `Employee`, not `IQueryable<Employee>` or `IEnumerable<Employee>` because it's just looking for the type parameters, not the actual types. I believe you also need an `Expression.Constant(dataContext.Employees)` instead of straight `dataContext.Employees`.

```
ParameterExpression employeesParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");
MemberExpression subordinatesProperty = Expression.Property(employeesParameter, typeof(Employee).GetProperty("Subordinates"));

MethodCallExpression hasSubordinates = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable),
    "Any",
    new Type[] { typeof(Employee) },
    subordinatesProperty);
LambdaExpression whereLambda = Expression.Lambda(hasSubordinates, employeesParameter);
MethodCallExpression whereExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable),
    "Where",
    new Type[] { typeof(Employee) },
    Expression.Constant(dataContext.Employees),
    whereLambda);
```

Comment: Still no good. I'm still getting the error: "No generic method 'Where' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic." against the whereExpression declaration.

Comment: I don't get that error. I have it compiling with the code above copy/pasted verbatim.

Answer (score 0):

To call `Any` for your `MemberExpression` you should do this

```
ParameterExpression employeesParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "e");
MemberExpression subordinatesProperty = Expression.Property(employeesParameter, typeof(Employee).GetProperty("Subordinates"));

var mi = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(x => x.Name == "Any" && x.GetParameters().Length == 1);
mi = mi.MakeGenericMethod(typeof (bool));
var hasSubordinates = Expression.Call(mi, subordinatesProperty);
```

and `Where`

```
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, bool>>(hasSubordinates, employeesParameter);
var res = i.Where(lambda.Compile());
```

Comment: This doesn't compile. Where did you declare "i" in var res = i.Where(lambda.Compile());??

Comment: i is whatever enumerable